# Is it possible to infer bijectivity of a function from an existing function that you know is bijective?

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose we know that $f : M \rightarrow N$ is a homeomorphism.

And we are given $g : M \rightarrow N$ that we know is injective and smooth.

Does it follow that $g$ is also bijective? And how would we prove this?

I am also most interested in the case where $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds of the same dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function
$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f : & \mathbb R & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R_+\\
    & x & \longmapsto & e^x \end{array}$$

is an homeomorphism.

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
g : & \mathbb R & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R_+\\
    & x & \longmapsto & e^x +1\end{array}$$

is smooth an injective, but not bijective.

Comment: Even simpler: $g(x) = e^x$ is an injective smooth function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which is not bijective.

Comment: If $M$ and $N$ are both compact does that change things? For more context, I was trying to prove something is diffeomorphic without finding an inverse.

Comment: Looks like this question would hold in the compact case, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890112/continuous-proper-injective-map-into-first-countable-space-is-homeomorphism-on