# Ends of image of a plane-curve

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**All maps between two topological spaces will assume to be continuous.**

$\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $X$ be a topological space. Two [proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map#:%7E:text=3%20Generalization-,Definition,point%20in%20Y%20is%20compact)  maps $a,b : [0,\infty) \to X$ are said to determine the same end of $X$ if the following holds: If $C \subseteq  X$ is compact then for any $t$ sufficiently large $(t\gg0)$, both $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ lie in the same component of $X - C$. The equivalence class of a proper map $a : [0,\infty) \to X$ is denoted $[a]$ and is called an end of $X$. The set of all ends of $X$ will be denoted by $\underline{\pi}_0(X)$.

*Note that for a proper map $f:X\to Y$ between two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ we have an induced map $\underline{\pi}_0(f): \underline{\pi}_0(X)\to \underline{\pi}_0(Y)$ defined by $[a]\longmapsto [f\circ a]$.*

---

> $\textbf{Problem 1:}$ Let $\gamma:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$ be a proper map. Consider
> the image set $\text{im}(\gamma)$ of the curve $\gamma$, and give the
> subspace topology on $\text{im}(\gamma)$ inherited from $\Bbb R^2$. Is
> it true that $\text{im}(\gamma)$ has exactly two ends?

*I think unless $\gamma$ is injective(i.e. [embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890112/continuous-proper-injective-map-into-first-countable-space-is-homeomorphism-on#:%7E:text=4-,Continuous%2C%20proper%2C%20injective%20map%20into%20first%2Dcountable,space%20is%20homeomorphism%20onto%20image&text=Theorem%3A%20Let%20X%2CY%20be,a%20homeomorphism%20into%20it%27s%20image.)) of $\Bbb R$ the above result is false; it may have infinitely many ends.*

> $\textbf{Problem 2:}$ Now, suppose $\delta:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$ is another proper
> map such that $\text{im}(\delta)$ has two ends. Is it true that
> $\underline{\pi}_0(\delta):\underline{\pi}_0(\Bbb R)\to
>  \underline{\pi}_0\big(\text{im}(\delta)\big)$ is a bijection?

---

**Edit after comment:**

> $\textbf{Problem 2.1.:}$ Let me rephrase $\text{Problem 2}$. Suppose
> $\delta:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$ is a proper   map. Hence,
> $\text{im}(\delta)$ has two ends. Dose there exist another proper map
> $\alpha:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$ with $\text{im}(\alpha)=\text{im}(\delta)$
> and   $\underline{\pi}_0(\alpha):\underline{\pi}_0(\Bbb
>  R)\longrightarrow  \underline{\pi}_0\big(\text{im}(\alpha)\big)=
>  \underline{\pi}_0\big(\text{im}(\delta)\big)$ is a bijection?

Comment: For P1: Try to prove that there are exactly two ends. For P2, try to prove the bijection.

Comment: You're going the wrong way; it can have only one end.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So, $a:=\gamma\big|[0,\infty)$ and $b:[0,\infty)\mapsto \gamma(-x)$ will represents two different ends of $\text{im}(\gamma)$. Right?

Comment: That's right. You just need to prove it.

Comment: @Mathlover Actually, I take it back: The map of the set of ends will be surjective but, in general, not injective. For some reason I thought about uniformly proper maps. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So, you are talking about Problem 2. Let me rephrase it. Suppose $\delta:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$ is another proper 
 map such that $\text{im}(\delta)$ has two ends. Dose there exist another proper map $\alpha:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$ with $\text{im}(\alpha)=\text{im}(\delta)$ and 
 $\underline{\pi}_0(\alpha):\underline{\pi}_0(\Bbb R)\longrightarrow
 \underline{\pi}_0\big(\text{im}(\alpha)\big)= \underline{\pi}_0\big(\text{im}(\delta)\big)$ is a bijection?

Comment: **Image of $\gamma$ has at most two ends:** Write, $X=\text{im}(\gamma)$. Let $e:[0,\infty)\to X$ represent another end. If possible let, $e$ be not equivalent to $a:=\gamma\big|[0,\infty)$ and $b:[0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto\gamma(-t)$. So, there is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ and and a positive constant $t_K$ such that we have three different, hence pairwise-disjoint components $\mathcal C_a,\mathcal C_b,\mathcal C_e$ of $X\backslash K$ with $a[t_K,\infty)\subseteq \mathcal C_a,b[t_K,\infty)\subseteq \mathcal C_b,e[t_K,\infty)\subseteq \mathcal C_e$.

Comment: Now, $\gamma[-t_K,t_K]\supseteq\text{im}(\gamma)\backslash \big\{\gamma(t):|t|\geq t_K\big\}=X\backslash \big(a[t_K,\infty)\cup b[t_k,\infty)\big)\supseteq X\backslash\big(\mathcal C_a\cup \mathcal C_b)$. Hence, $\mathcal C_e\subseteq X\backslash\big(\mathcal C_a\cup \mathcal C_b) \subseteq \gamma[-t_K,t_K]$, so $e[t_K,\infty)\subseteq \gamma[-t_K,t_K]=\text{compact}$, but $e$ is a proper map, a contradiction. **Am I missing something?**

Comment: **I hope the image of this proper curve has exactly one end:** Consider the proper map $\gamma:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $$\gamma(t)=\begin{cases}(\cos 2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t)& \text{ if }|t|\leq 1;\\ (|t|,0)&\text{ if }|t|\geq 1.\end{cases}$$ Am I right?

Comment: Yes that sounds about right, @Mathlover

Comment: Your example is correct but unnecessarily complicated. Hint: Use an example whose image lies in the x-axis. As for P2: Use the fact that each surjective map between finite sets of the same cardinality is bijective.